# How do I calculate percentages of subcategories using category total as denominator in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, grouping, percentage

I am trying to create a table that shows three columns:

individuals = DISTINCTCOUNT(‘tbl’[personID])  // everyone in the population

waivered = CALCULATE([individuals], ‘tbl’[Waiver] = “Y”)   // count of those with waivers

Percent waivered = DIVIDE([waivered], [individuals], 0)

[image]

As you can see the population percentages are correct, but I'd like the children's Settings percentages to be based on the Children's total (229).

I have been unable to create such a measure but the Settings values should be:  C = 3/229 = 1.3%; D = 24/229 = 10.5%; E = 5/229 = 2.2%.
Each line currently takes the base number in that line so that I’m getting 100% for each category. I’ve tried using various iterations of ALL(), and REMOVEFILTERS(), etc.  and setting the count of waivered as percent of grand total, etc…

Is it possible to create a measure that will correctly evaluate both the group (population) and subgroup (Setting) using the subgroup total as the denominator?